# Only update changed item in listview in .net maui

Tags: .net, maui

I have a listview with a swipeview per element which has either leftitems or rightitems depending on which property is set. One such a property is "IsSelected" which will be set to true by the viewmodel if the given item is selected in the listview. In order for the properties new value to be seen by the listview i am notifying that the entire ItemsSource (i.e. the list) has changed. But you can imagine how inefficient this is. Is there a way to force listview only to render the item which property has been changed?

Edit -- Sources added:

The view (xaml):

```
   <ListView 
   Grid.Row="1"
   x:Name="ListView" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Coins}"
   ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected"
   SelectionMode="Single"
   HasUnevenRows="True"
   Scrolled="ListView_Scrolled">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <SwipeView>
                   <SwipeView.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger TargetType="SwipeView">
                           <DataTrigger.Binding>
                               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBooleanConverter}">
                                   <Binding Path="IsInPortfolio" />
                                   <Binding Path="IsSelected" />
                               </MultiBinding>
                           </DataTrigger.Binding>
                           
                           <DataTrigger.Value>
                               <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                           </DataTrigger.Value>
                           
                           <Setter Property="LeftItems">
                               <Setter.Value>
                                   <SwipeItems>
                                       <SwipeItem Text="Delete" Invoked="DeleteInvoked">
                                           <SwipeItem.CommandParameter>
                                               <x:Reference Name="ListView" />
                                           </SwipeItem.CommandParameter>
                                       </SwipeItem>
                                   </SwipeItems>
                               </Setter.Value>
                           </Setter>
                       </DataTrigger>

                       <DataTrigger TargetType="SwipeView">

                           <DataTrigger.Binding>
                               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBooleanConverter}">
                                   <Binding Path="IsNotInPortfolio" />
                                   <Binding Path="IsSelected" />
                               </MultiBinding>
                           </DataTrigger.Binding>

                           <DataTrigger.Value>
                               <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                           </DataTrigger.Value>

                           <Setter Property="RightItems">
                               <Setter.Value>
                                   <SwipeItems>
                                       <SwipeItem Text="Add" Invoked="AddInvoked">
                                           <SwipeItem.CommandParameter>
                                               <x:Reference Name="ListView" />
                                           </SwipeItem.CommandParameter>
                                       </SwipeItem>
                                   </SwipeItems>
                               </Setter.Value>
                           </Setter>
                       </DataTrigger>
                   </SwipeView.Triggers>

                   <Grid
                       RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto"
                       ColumnDefinitions="Auto, Auto">
                       <Image
                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           WidthRequest="60"
                           HeightRequest="60"
                           Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"
                           Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                       <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto" Padding="10, 10, 0, 0" Grid.Column="1">
                           <Label
                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                           <Label
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Text="{Binding Symbol}"/>
                           <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding IsInPortfolio, StringFormat='Is added: {0}'}" Margin="10" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                       </Grid>
                   </Grid>
               </SwipeView>
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The view model:

```
public class CoinsViewModel : ICoinsViewModel
{
    private Coin? _selectedCoin;
    private CoinCategory _selectedCategory;

    private ObservableCollection<Coin> _coins = [];
    public IList<Coin> Coins
    {
        get
        {
            return _coins.Where(p => p.Category == _selectedCategory).ToList();
        }
    }

    public Coin? SelectedCoin
    {
        get => _selectedCoin;
        set
        {
            _selectedCoin = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedCoin)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public void SelectCategory(int index)
    {
        _selectedCategory = (CoinCategory)(1 << index);
        SelectedCoin = null;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Coins)));
    }

    public void AddCoin(Coin coin)
    {
        coin.IsInPortfolio = true;
        coin.IsNotInPortfolio = false;
        coin.IsSelected = false;
        SelectedCoin = null;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Coins)));
    }

    public void SelectCoin(Coin coin)
    {
        if (SelectedCoin != null && coin != SelectedCoin)
            SelectedCoin.IsSelected = false;

        SelectedCoin = coin;
        SelectedCoin.IsSelected = true;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Coins)));
    }

    public void DeleteCoin(Coin coin)
    {
        coin.IsInPortfolio = false;
        coin.IsNotInPortfolio = true;
        coin.IsSelected = false;
        SelectedCoin = null;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Coins)));
    }
}
```

And the coin model:

```
public class Coin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string IconSource { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CoinCategory Category { get; set; }
    public bool IsInPortfolio { get; set; }
    public bool IsNotInPortfolio { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I already tried implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in my coin model, but didnt work. The reason i initially didnt provide any code was because i wasnt even sure ListView supports per item notification and wanted to be sure it does.

EDIT 2:

Okay guys, it worked. The error is obvious: I dont return ObservableCollection but a subset of that which of course is not the initial object.

When property Coins is changed to

```
public ObservableCollection<Coin> Coins { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Coin>();
```

it works. Nvm..

Comment: Make IsSelected Observable

Comment: Please show the code you're currently dealing with instead of only explaining what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Julian Done. Source added.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `Coin` model observable, so that property changes get propagated *(this is using the [MVVM Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/overview))*:

```cs
public partial class Coin : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _symbol;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private double _price;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _iconSource;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _description;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private CoinCategory _category;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isInPortfolio;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isNotInPortfolio = true;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isSelected;
}
```

Then you can get rid of all the

```cs
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Coins)));
```

calls.

And for the binding source:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Coin> Coins { get; set; } = [];
```

If you frequently change the referenced collection, you might need to make that observable as well:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Coin> _coins = [];
public ObservableCollection<Coin> Coins
{
    get => _coins;
    set
    {
        if(_coins == value) return;
        _coins = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Coins)));
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that the ViewModel implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. I decided to keep the code close to what you already have for the ViewModel using a vanilla implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Only update changed item in listview in .net maui

For this, you can implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your Item model and call method `OnPropertyChanged` for the properties you want to update.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }


    //public string Description { get; set; }
    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _description, value);
        }
    }


    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value);
        }
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Note:**

1.I called method `SetProperty()` for property `Description` and property  `IsSelected`, if we change the value of `Description` or property  `IsSelected`, the UI will refresh itself.

2.You can also use nuget [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) to achieve this.
You can inherit base class [ObservableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject).

```
public partial class Item:ObservableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    string description;

    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isSelected;
}
```